# forma otimizada para recuperar último ID mysql

Tags: mysql, select

Qual forma mais otimizada de recuperar o último id da tabela?

testei esses dois métodos e o orde by demorou muito. Existe algum além desses?

Obs: nãp será uma consulta após insert. Será uma consulta separada.

```
select max(campo_id) from tabela

select campo_id FROM tabela ORDER BY campo_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Nenhuma dessas é pra recuperar o último ID. Estas são para recuperar o Maior ID. Geralmente eles coincidem, mas não é uma verdade absoluta.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nenhuma dessas alternativas serve para recuperar o último ID.

Seu código é para recuperar o Maior ID. Geralmente o último e o maior coincidem, mas não é uma verdade absoluta.

Para saber o último ID inserido automaticamente, o código é esse:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID;
```

Lembrando ainda que nem precisa do `SELECT` na maior parte das situações, se estiver usando uma biblioteca de MySQL em outra linguagem, ou mesmo o conector em C, é comum ter função específica que já retorna o valor logo após o `INSERT`.

Mas tenha em mente que isto **só funciona se você fez a última inserção na mesma conexão**.

**Nem tudo são flores:** se a última inserção acrescentou 3 registros no DB, esta função retorna o primeiro deles, e não o último.

Como você disse que é uma consulta separada, o que pode ajudar é esta consulta que retorna o **próximo** ID automático que será usado:

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  table_name = 'nome da sua tabela'
AND    table_schema = 'nome do seu DB' ;
```

### Mas então, qual o problema do código da pergunta?

Se você quer realmente saber o último inserido, o único recurso seguro é recuperar o dado com `LAST_INSERT_ID`, ou exagerando, fazendo um *trigger* para isto.

Por exemplo, veja situações comuns em que o código da pergunta não vai retornar o último valor inserido:

- Se os últimos registros forem deletados, o `LAST_INSERT_ID` ainda vai conter o valor inserido, mas o código da pergunta recuperará os ID anteriores a estes (que não corresponderão aos das próximas inserções).
- Se for feita uma inserção especificando um ID manualmente, menor do que o inserido, não há jeito seguro de saber qual foi o último.

**Agora, tem que pensar numa coisa importante:** dependendo do uso que você for fazer, você não precisa realmente do último inserido, e sim do maior existente. Neste caso, o código da pergunta resolve.

Alternativamente, você pode usar a técnica do `SELECT AUTOINCREMENT` acima, e subtrair `1` para estimar qual era o anterior. Isto **também não garante** que realmente foi o último inserido, mas tem menos probabilidade de dar efeitos colaterais.

**Outro cuidado a tomar**: pode muito bem acontecer de ocorrer alguma outra transação no DB, e esse valor alterar antes de você usar, então qualquer coisa que fuja do `LAST_INSERT_ID` pode gerar uma *race condition*. O ideal é não usar o valor para nada que não seja realmente referenciar a última linha inserida.

**Mais um alerta:** (para complicar ainda mais a vida) você só deve usar o `LAST_INSERT_ID` se a última inserção não deu erro, senão pode estar pegando um ID de inserção anterior. Tem gente que **testa se deu zero** para saber se retornou um ID ou não, mas isto **não é confiável** se não conferir se o `INSERT` realmente teve sucesso.

Quanto à performance, o único jeito de se ter certeza, é fazendo *benchmarks*, pois depende de uma série de fatores.

Comment: Obrigado @Bacco

Comment: @ThallesDaniel dei uma resposta genérica, mas se explicar melhor pra que vai usar o valor, ou tiver mais alguma dúvida, deixe um comentário que posso tentar ajudar.

Comment: de inicio é pra gerar um protocolo antes dele mesmo existir mas tenho um problema de concorrência ou atendente pode gerar ao mesmo tempo ai vi alguns métodos para bloquear a tabela mas não acreditei que seria o melhor caminho

Comment: @ThallesDaniel se precisa de um protocolo antes de ter os dados, tem 2 caminhos mais comuns: Um é uma tabela separada de protocolos, em que vc gera o protocolo e depois vincula a um registro maior. Outro jeito é inserir uma ficha incompleta no DB, e dar um update durante o atendimento. Qualquer dessas alternativas vai te dar um ID. A idéia do protocolo é justamente essa, o simples fato de haver um atendimento tem que gerar isso, e armazenar, mesmo que o atendimento seja descartado ou incompleto. Ao menos vc vai ter o protocolo (ID), a data e a hora da ocorrência.

Comment: Inclusive, é o mais correto até para diagnósticos. Amanha ou depois vc pode fazer uma pesquisa, e perceber que o atendente X tem 300 protocolos, mas só 100 atendimentos, e isso é sinal que tem algo errado. E neste caso, vc estará usando o LAST_INSERT_ID assim que criar o protocolo, então é perfeitamente seguro e sem problemas de concorrência, e não precisa de LOCK, transações e outras coisas problemáticas.

Comment: vlw mesmo esse caminho clareou muito. Pra auditoria fica bem melhor msm

Answer (score 0):

No MySQL é bem fácil. Eu estava tentando fazer a mesma coisa no SQL Server e é um sacrifício.

No MySQL você só precisa usar [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

Exemplo: `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @tabela`