# Receber ID do POST e jogar para Location via GET

Tags: php, html, mysql, get, id

estou preciando pegar a ID da entidade que acabou de ser cadastrada. Só que ela será jogado para outra tela, para ser cadastrado outras informações. Gostaria de saber como posso pegar a ID da entidade ao salvar o formulário.

Esse é o HTML

```html
<form action="set.php" method="post">

  <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label">*Nome</label>
   <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="">
   </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label">Sobrenome</label>
   <input type="text" id="sobrenome" name="sobrenome" class="form-control" placeholder="">
  </div>
  </div>
```

E esse é o PHP

```html
<?php

$nome                = $_POST ["nome"];  
$sobrenome           = $_POST ["sobrenome"]; 

$sql = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO gr_entidade (nome, sobrenome ) VALUES ('$nome', '$sobrenome')");

header("Location: usuario?id=id");
?>
```

```html
header("Location: usuario?id=id");
```

Podem me dar uma ajuda ?

Comment: mysql_insert_id - Obtém o ID gerado pela operação INSERT anterior http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: LAST_INSERT_ID - só funciona se você fez a última inserção na mesma conexão. Se a última inserção acrescentou 3 registros no DB, esta função retorna o primeiro deles, e não o último. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127456/forma-otimizada-recuperar-ultimo-id-mysql

Comment: Faça `header("Location: outrapagina.php?id=" . mysql_insert_id());` e na outra pagina receba assim `<div><?php echo $_GET['id']; ?></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Conforme documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-insert-id.php):

Use: `mysql_insert_id()`.

Ex.:

```
<?php

$nome                = $_POST ["nome"];  
$sobrenome           = $_POST ["sobrenome"]; 

$sql = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO gr_entidade (nome, sobrenome ) VALUES ('$nome', '$sobrenome')");

$last_id = mysql_insert_id();

header("Location: usuario?id=$last_id");
?>
```

Vale ressaltar que a extensão `mysql` está obsoleta, conforme a mesma documentação:

> **Aviso** Esta extensão está obsoleta desde o PHP 5.5.0 e foi removida no
>   PHP 7.0.0. Utilize MySQLi ou PDO_MySQL alternativamente. Veja também
>   MySQL: escolhendo uma API e FAQs relacionadas para mais informações.
>   Alternativas a essa função incluem:
>
> [mysqli_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.insert-id.php)
>
> [PDO::lastInsertId()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

É recomendável migrar para as extensões **mysqli** ou **PDO**.

Comment: Funcionou muito bem!

Answer (score 1):

Para capturar o último ID adicionado, basta executar a query sql.

```
mysql_query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
```

Ou você pode usar a função **[mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-insert-id.php)**

Comment: Obrigado. Usei a função  mysql_insert_id e deu certo