# Pegar o ultimo ID do Insert prepare

Tags: php

Como faço para pegar o ultimo `ID` criado pelo `insert`?

```
$rs = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tabela (campo1, campo2, campo3) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ");

    $rs->bind_param('sss',
        $_POST['campo1'],
        $_POST['campo2'],
        $_POST['campo3']
        );

    $rs->execute();


    if ($rs->errno) {
        echo 'Erro: ', $rs->error;
    } else {
        echo "<script>window.location='PAGINA.php'</script>";
    }
```

É só usar `$ultimoId=  $rs->insert_id;`?

Ai posso fazer assim?

```
$rs->execute();
$ultimoId = $rs->insert_id;

    if ($rs->errno) {
        echo 'Erro: ', $rs->error;
    } else {
        echo "<script>window.location='PAGINA.php?id=$ultimoId'</script>";
    }
```

Comment: a variável $rs é seu objeto de conexão? poste seu código completo para que possamos entender direito o que são as variáveis

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127456/forma-otimizada-recuperar-ultimo-id-mysql

Comment: @JulyanoFelipe, `$mysqli` é a variavel que tem os dados do banco de dados. `$rs` é o que recebe o insert e executa.

Comment: @Tiago então o que você está procurando seria `$conn->insert_id`;

Comment: é só usar `$mysql->insert_id `

Answer (score -3):

Você pode usar o método:

```
$mysqli->lastInsertId()
```

Retorna o ID da última linha inserida

Comment: Existe esse método na MySQLi? Isso não é coisa do PDO?